# Access to the provided image was forbidden using batchUpdate of Google Docs REST API

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google Docs REST API batchUpdate to replace images in a Docs file. When I first created the code, I had a permission error and I saw a couple of posts that actually solved this:

1. [Using Google Docs API to Insert Image From Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63309338/using-google-docs-api-to-insert-image-from-google-drive)
2. [Access to the provided image was forbidden even though it was uploaded from the same account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70311191/access-to-the-provided-image-was-forbidden-even-though-it-was-uploaded-from-the)

This has been working, but for some reason after some time I get the same error even though nothing has changed. The image I used is still shared publicly (Anyone with the link).

I need to use a service account for this one.

The error I get:

error={message=Invalid requests[12].replaceImage: Access to the provided image was forbidden., code=400.0, status=INVALID_ARGUMENT}

My code snippet:

```
function postGoogleAPI(url, payload){
  var service = getOAuthService();
  service.reset();


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    contentType : "application/json",
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() // a function that gets the access token
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  });

  return JSON.parse(response);
}

function getGoogleAPI(url) {
  var service = getOAuthService();
  service.reset();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() // a function that gets the access token
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  });

  return response;

}


function getReplaceImageRequest(imageFileId, docsFileId, mergeField) {
  let requestData = [];

  let url = Utilities.formatString("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%s?supportsAllDrives=true&fields=webContentLink", imageFileId);
  let response = getGoogleAPI(url);

  let logoUri = JSON.parse(response).webContentLink

  url = Utilities.formatString("https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/%s?fields=inlineObjects", docsFileId);
  response = getGoogleAPI(url);

  let inlineObjects = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 

  for(const key in inlineObjects.inlineObjects){
    let title = inlineObjects.inlineObjects[key].inlineObjectProperties.embeddedObject.title;

    if(title != null && title == mergeField){
      requestData.push({
        "replaceImage": {
          "imageObjectId": key,
          "uri": logoUri,
          "imageReplaceMethod": "CENTER_CROP"
        }
      });
    }

  }

  return requestData;
}

getReplaceImageRequest(<id of image file>, <Docs file id>, <identifier of merge field>);

let url = "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/<id of Docs file>:batchUpdate";
let payload = {
    "requests" : requests
  }
  
let response = postGoogleAPI(url, payload); // Error occurs here
```

I've tried manually resetting the general access type with no success. If I upload a new image, it works though.

So in summary, the code works until for some reason the image is not accessible anymore, even with access type still set to 'Anyone with the link'.

I hope anyone can help here, thanks in advance!

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `This has been working, but for some reason after some time I get the same error even though nothing has changed.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: What's the data in the `requests` variable within the payload?

Comment: And one more question, how often are you accessing this image? I found [a thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150933939) that suggests that this error message could be a misnamed quota limit.

Comment: @Tanaike, the code works. I uploaded a new image and set it to publicly available, I can replace images in the Docs file with it. And it worked multiple times. I did not touch it for about a week, then it fails showing the error message. Nothing was changed, not the code, not the image, nor the image's access type.

Comment: @Daniel sorry the requests is the return value of the function. I just copied snippets to make the code short. The image was not accessed for a week or so. It's still not live, and mainly used in testing. I'll review the thread you posted, but I doubt if this is quota related as the image was not accessed quite some time. Unless there is a limit on how many times the image can be accessed regardless of duration, but that does not make sense. Thanks!

Comment: So I just tried it again now, with the image I uploaded yesterday, and I get the same error. I probably tested it successfully 2-3 times yesterday. It's like the access type is not recognized correctly after some time. It was uploaded ~20 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem, at least my update has not failed so far. The problem was in the code that gets the link of the image (/?supportsAllDrives=true&fields=webContentLink). I changed it to /?supportsAllDrives=true&fields=thumbnailLink and this works so far. So for some reason the webContentLink field value changes after some time, and results in the error I encountered.